# Payment Navigation form php to payment gateway and back to php (response back to php page )

Tags: javascript, php, transactions, instamojo

i created a login.php file where the user can will be navigated to instamojo payment page . After completing the transaction the user is getting the success message from instamojo , but i  need to display the successful transaction in my domain or in own php file . so how can i get the transation related information to my webpage or to my login.php file

Ex: Redirecting from our login.php to instamojo(payment gateway)and response back (success message)to our login.php intimating the user that payment is success

```js
var rootURL = "cgshealthcare.com/HealthCareSystem/";;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login').click(function() {
    if ($('#username').val() == "" || $('#password').val() == "") {
      alert("Please enter username or password");
      return false;
    }
    cardloginUser($('#username').val(), $('#password').val());
  });
});

function forwardtoRegister() {
  window.location = "login.php?page=register";
}

function cardloginUser(userName, password) {
  console.log('userName: ' + userName);
  console.log('password: ' + password);
  if (userName.length < 1) {
    $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b> Please enter User ID</b></font>");
    return false;
  }
  if (password.length < 1) {
    $('#errorlist').html(" <font color='red'><b> Please enter Password</b></font>");
    return false;
  }
  console.log(rootURL + '/authenticate/' + userName + '/' + password);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL + '/authenticate/' + userName + '/' + password,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("hello" + data.responseMessageDetails);
      var list = data == null ? [] : (data.responseMessageDetails instanceof Array ? data.responseMessageDetails : [data.responseMessageDetails]);
      console.log("List : " + list);
      if ((list).length < 1) {
        $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b> Invalid User Name and Password Combination </b></font>");
        $('#errorblock').css("visibility") == "visible";
      }
      $.each(list, function(index, responseMessageDetails) {
        console.log("Status " + responseMessageDetails);
        var message = responseMessageDetails.message;
        if (message.indexOf("]:") > 0) message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("]:") + 2);
        console.log("message" + message);
        console.log("USer Data" + responseMessageDetails.status);
        console.log("USer Data" + responseMessageDetails.message);
        if (responseMessageDetails.status == "Success") {
          window.location = "imjo.in/NpKxN";;
        } else if (responseMessageDetails.status == "Fail") {
          window.location = "www.google.com";
          console.log("Fail1");
          $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>" + message + "</b></font>");
        } else {
          console.log("Fail111");
          $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b> We are sorry some intermittent Issue. Please try after some time. </b></font>");
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("data...." + data);
      var list = data == null ? [] : (data.responseMessageDetails instanceof Array ? data.responseMessageDetails : [data.responseMessageDetails]);
      console.log("data...." + data);
      $.each(list, function(index, responseMessageDetails) {
        console.log(responseMessageDetails);
        var message = responseMessageDetails.message;
        if (message.indexOf("]:") > 0) message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("]:") + 2);
        $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>" + message + "</b></font>");
      });
    }
  });
}

function showLogin() {
  window.location = "login.php";
}
```

Comment: var rootURL = "http://cgshealthcare.com/HealthCareSystem/";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function() {
   if($('#username').val() == "" || $('#password').val() == ""){
   alert("Please enter username or password");
   return false;
  }
   cardloginUser($('#username').val(),$('#password').val());});            
});
function forwardtoRegister(){

     window.location = "login.php?page=register";
 }

Comment: function cardloginUser(userName,password) {
    console.log('userName: ' + userName);
    console.log('password: ' + password);
       if(userName.length < 1){
        $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>  Please enter User ID</b></font>");
        return false;
    }
    if(password.length < 1){
        $('#errorlist').html(" <font color='red'><b>  Please enter Password</b></font>");
        return false;
    }
    console.log(rootURL + '/authenticate/' + userName +'/'+password);
 $.ajax({

Comment: type: 'GET',
  url: rootURL + '/authenticate/' + userName +'/'+password,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
   console.log("hello"+data.responseMessageDetails);
                      var list = data == null ? [] : (data.responseMessageDetails instanceof Array ? data.responseMessageDetails : [data.responseMessageDetails]);

Comment: console.log("List : "+list);
                        if((list).length < 1 ){

Comment: $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>  Invalid User Name and Password Combination </b></font>");
                             $('#errorblock').css("visibility") == "visible";

                          } 
                          $.each(list, function(index, responseMessageDetails) {
                           console.log("Status   "+responseMessageDetails);

Comment: var message = responseMessageDetails.message;
                           if(message.indexOf("]:") > 0)
                             message = message.substring(0,message.indexOf("]:")+2);
                           console.log("message"+message);
                           console.log("USer

Comment: Data"+responseMessageDetails.status);
                           console.log("USer Data"+responseMessageDetails.message);
                           if(responseMessageDetails.status == "Success"){
                                window.location = "https://imjo.in/NpKxN";
                             
                               
                           }else if(responseMessageDetails.status == "Fail"){
          window.location =

Comment: "www.google.com"; 
          console.log("Fail1");
                               $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>"+message+"</b></font>");
                           }else {
           console.log("Fail111");

Comment: $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b> We are sorry some intermittent Issue. Please try after some time. </b></font>");
                           } });},
        error: function(data){

Comment: console.log("data...."+data);
           var list = data == null ? [] : (data.responseMessageDetails instanceof Array ? data.responseMessageDetails : [data.responseMessageDetails]);
           console.log("data...."+data);
            $.each(list, function(index, responseMessageDetails) {
                 console.log(responseMessageDetails);
                var message = responseMessageDetails.message;
                if(message.indexOf("]:") > 0)
                  message = message.substring(0,message.indexOf("]:")+2);

Comment: $('#errorlist').html("<font color='red'><b>"+message+"</b></font>");
            });
                         }
 });
        
   
}
function showLogin(){
     window.location = "login.php";
}

Comment: please don't code here... add in your question we will format it

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [integration guide here](https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/payments-api).

After user enters payment information on instamojo, they are redirected to a redirect-url which you specify (and is a url on your website). Instamojo appends transaction results to this url. You can make it a php url on your website and read the results using GET method. Depending upon the results, you can process your payment and display results to the end-user. [More on GET method here...](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Instamojo also provides for webhooks, which are like silent POSTs in the background and can be used as backups in case redirect urls in front-end fail for some reason. This way if end-users' redirection failed for any reason, the webhook will still receive information in the background which can be used you to update your database for success/failure of transaction. Of course you webserver has to be up and running to receive webhooks notifications. If that's the point of failure, nothing will work :)

The API link I shared has all those details.

Thanks